# Fatal Error: Public Main() method is required in a public class

Tags: c#, .net

Trying my hands on some C# what could be wrong here, i saw it in a text but i keep getting the error

> Fatal Error: Public Main() method is required in a public class

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace Beee
    {
        class SampleProgram
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                object[] o = new object[] {"1", 4.0, "Abuja", 'B'};
                fun(o);
            }
            static void fun(params object[] obj)
            {
                for(int i=0; i<obj.Length-1; i++)
                Console.Write(obj[i] +"");
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: Did you read the error message?  What do you think "Main() is required to be in a public class" means?

Comment: What program is showing you that error?

Comment: Please see [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 4):

It's because the IDE you're using--dot net fiddle is an example that does this--requires making `Main` a `public` method in a `public` class in order to run your code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace Beee
{
    public class SampleProgram // <-- make class public
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args) // <-- make Main method public
        {
            object[] o = new object[] {"1", 4.0, "Abuja", 'B'};
            fun(o);
        }
        static void fun(params object[] obj)
        {
            for(int i=0; i<obj.Length-1; i++)
                Console.Write(obj[i] +"");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your error:

> Fatal Error: Public Main() method is required in a **public** class

Microsoft Documentation:

> Classes and structs that are declared directly within a namespace (...) can be either public or internal. **Internal is the default if no access modifier is specified.**

Source: [Access Modifiers (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/access-modifiers#class-and-struct-accessibility).

Your code:

```
namespace Beee
    {
        class SampleProgram
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                // ...
            }
        }
}
```

Rhetorical question: What is the access modifier of your class?

---

**Addendum**

Also note:

> Fatal Error: **Public Main()** method is required in a public class

---

*All emphasis mine.*

Answer (score 0):

Your application entry point does not meet the standards. [Check out this example.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/main-and-command-args/) Looks like you need to make everything [`public` keywords](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/public) when using namespaces.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace Beee
    {
        public class SampleProgram
        {
            public static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                object[] o = new object[] {"1", 4.0, "Abuja", 'B'};
                fun(o);
            }
            static void fun(params object[] obj)
            {
                for(int i=0; i<obj.Length-1; i++)
                Console.Write(obj[i] +"");
            }
        }
}
```